# How to strip away a certain case in a SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having problems figuring this out. This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE date('2012-9-4') >= start_date AND 
date('2012-9-4') <= end_date
```

Now as you can see from above, I am only getting the rows that match that day in some way. In my case, any events that are on that day or came from previous days. The problem is, the case where, say, the previous day has an event from 10:00PM to 12:00AM (2012-9-3), shows up on the next day (2012-9-4). So I need to keep the case like that from happening.

This is where I am having trouble. I have no idea how to get it done correctly. I have tried different things, but they all fail. I need a way to make a statement in the where clause only run when the `end date > start date`, the `end date == current day`, and the `end time == 00:00`. Any advice would be greatly apprecited!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you just need to turn around the first parts of the where clauses

```
Where start_date >= date ('2012-9-4') and end_date <= date('2012-9-4')
```

Assuming your data always has end_date later than start_date (if not, then adding an OR with the reverse to pick them up to).

If, (confused here from the Q) you actually want intersecting dates (overlaps), then you need two intersecting clauses:

```
where (start_date >= date('2012-09-03 00:00:00') and start_date < date('2012-09-04 00:00:00')) or (end_date >= date('2012-09-03 00:00:00') and end_date < date('2012-09-04 00:00:00'))
```

Comment: Nope. In fact it makes it worse. Nothing shows up. But even if you were right, it wouldn't exclude the case I am trying to delete from the returned rows. Good try though. Appreciate the time :)

Comment: It was bothering me why your way wasn't working (even though it didn't solve my problem), and I just realized why. I have to include dates that fall within the dates in some way. Which means, dates that come before the or equal to the start date, but end before or on the end date.

Comment: I think your question needs to be clearer then - I can not see how my answer doesn't answer your question - so I must not be understanding your question correctly. Do you want dates that intersect the start/end dates or that are entirely within them? I thought (from your q) the latter, but maybe you want the former???

Comment: Its like a Calendar. So even when an event starts before the current day, it will still come up in the current day if the event calls for it. Thats why I have it in that way. But thats also where my issue occurs, since technically midnight is the next day, I need it to not come up at all. But with my current query it has to appear due to what I need. I just don't need it to happen like that in that one situation, when the end time is midnight.

Comment: Think you want to add the time and use less than that day's midnight, and greater than equal to on the previous day's midnight plus (for start). I ammended my answer, but this is using your one-day case, and will need ammendment to cover in-between day capture for date ranges if required (events over a day in length).

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out (pretty sure)!

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE date('2012-9-4') >= start_date AND 
date('2012-9-5') <= end_date AND datetime(end_date,end_time) != datetime(2012-9-5,'00:00')
```

After 2 days of thinking, I have no idea why using the time as well never occurred to me. I guess I need more practice with databases. In any case, the part I added filters the events listed by date and time. Example would be like my query dates, lets say 11:00PM the 4th to 12:00AM the 5th. The `AND datetime(end_date,end_time) != datetime(2012-9-5,'00:00')` essentially says "only output when its not the end date with a time of midnight." It will only filter out the 5th and not the 4th because midnight is technically another day. Thats the only case I ever want to filter out events anymore than just between the event periods. I appreciate Wolf5370 for the hints which helped.